# npx react-native init fails due to Maximum call stack size exceeded npm error

Tags: react-native, npm, npx

Hi I am trying to set up my first react-native app by following the "React Native CLI Quickstart" guide on the official docs, but I am stuck at actually creating the react-native application by executing `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`, the command prompt output is as follows:

```
 npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded  

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:        
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-02T21_19_44_629Z-debug.log
 Install for [ 'react-native@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

And here is the relevant error in the debug log:

```
10480 verbose stack RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
10480 verbose stack     at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
10480 verbose stack     at isDepOptional (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:432:45)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:441:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10480 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:457:9)
10481 verbose cwd C:\Users\Lee
10482 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
10483 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-native@latest" "--global" "--prefix" "C:\\Users\\Lee\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\19364" "--loglevel" "error" "--json"
10484 verbose node v14.5.0
10485 verbose npm  v6.14.5
10486 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
10487 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried clearing the npm cache as mentioned in several other posts regarding a similar issue, but to no avail. I have also tried uninstalling `react-native-cli` from npm, which I never installed manually. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

That usually works for me.

Comment: As stated by OG, cache was cleared already, problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the node_modules folder and, if you can't, address whatever is preventing you from doing so.

I appear to have run into this dependency looping issue as a result of a recent IT update placing the directory containing the previously-working project under OneDrive's control.

In my case force cleaning the cache also had no effect, and the node_modules folder was shown as being "synced" by OneDrive and could not be deleted.

Moving the project folder (without the node_modules folder) back outside of OneDrive's jurisdiction allowed npm install to run without errors.

Answer (score -1):

you are updating some state value in render function. It try to update state value but it got stuck in infinite loop. Please show you code where this happens.

Comment: But I haven't written any code yet, the command is supposed to create the necessary boilerplates for a react-native app